# Does assignment with advanced indexing copy array data?

Tags: python, numpy, copy

I am slowly trying to understand the difference between `view`s and `copy`s in numpy, as well as mutable vs. immutable types.

If I access part of an array with ['advanced indexing'](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) it is supposed to return a copy.  This seems to be true:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: a = np.zeros((3,3))
In [3]: b = np.array(np.identity(3), dtype=bool)

In [4]: c = a[b]

In [5]: c[:] = 9

In [6]: a
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Since `c` is just a copy, it does not share data and changing it does not mutate `a`.  However, this is what confuses me:

```
In [7]: a[b] = 1

In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

So, it seems, even if I use advanced indexing, assignment still treats the thing on the left as a view.  Clearly the `a` in line 2 is the same object/data as the `a` in line 6, since mutating `c` has no effect on it.

So my question: is the `a` in line 8 the same object/data as before (not counting the diagonal of course) or is it a copy?  In other words, was `a`'s data copied to the new `a`, or was its data mutated in place?

For example, is it like:

```
x = [1,2,3]
x += [4]
```

or like:

```
y = (1,2,3)
y += (4,)
```

I don't know how to check for this because in either case, `a.flags.owndata` is `True`.  Please feel free to elaborate or answer a different question if I'm thinking about this in a confusing way.

Comment: See a nice summary of views vs copies [here](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do `c = a[b]`, `a.__get_item__` is called with `b` as its only argument, and whatever gets returned is assigned to `c`.

When you do`a[b] = c`, `a.__setitem__` is called with `b` and `c` as arguments and whatever gets returned is silently discarded.

So despite having the same `a[b]` syntax, both expressions are doing different things. You could subclass `ndarray`, overload this two functions, and have them behave differently. As is by default in numpy, the former returns a copy (if `b` is an array) but the latter modifies `a` in place.

Comment: I think it whould be worth to point out explicitly in numpy documentation the fact that even advanced indexing when used as lvalue will modify the original array.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is the same object.  Here's how you check:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> a2 = a
>>> a[b] = 1
>>> a2 is a
True
>>> a2
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Assigning to some expression in Python is not the same as just reading the value of that expression.  When you do `c = a[b]`, with `a[b]` on the right of the equals sign, it returns a new object.  When you do `a[b] = 1`, with `a[b]` on the left of the equals sign, it modifies the original object.

In fact, an expression like `a[b] = 1` *cannot* change what name `a` is bound to.  The code that handles `obj[index] = value` only gets to know the object `obj`, not what name was used to refer to that object, so it can't change what that name refers to.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be common misunderstanding, quoting from the official document: 
(https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html)

> The rule of thumb here can be: in the context of lvalue indexing (i.e.
>   the indices are placed in the left hand side value of an assignment),
>   no view or copy of the array is created (because there is no need to).
>   However, with regular values, the above rules for creating views does
>   apply.

In other words, the notion of `view` or `copy` only refers to the situation of retrieving values from a `numpy` object.