# Composite Index updates for Numpy Matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to update a set of particular rows and columns of a numpy matrix . Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.zeros((8,8))
rows=[0, 1, 5]
columns=[2, 3]
#(What I am trying to achieve) The following does not update A
A[rows][:,columns]+=1
#while this just does
for i in rows:
    A[i][columns]+=1
```

the output I am expecting is:

```
In [1]:print(A)
Out[1]: 
    array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Is there a way to perform a multiple-columnwise and -rowwise updates at the same time without looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing with arrays or lists of indices falls under the category of [fancy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays), and always generates a copy of the relevant portion of the array rather than giving you a view onto the original data.

Assignment or in-place modification of the result of a *single* fancy indexing operation works fine, (e.g. `A[rows] += 1`). However, modifying the result of *chained* indexing expressions, e.g. `A[rows][:, columns]`, will *not* work if the first expression uses fancy indexing. The reason is that `A[rows]` generates a copy, so adding 1 to `A[rows][:, columns]` will not affect `A`.

You can avoid this problem if you do all of your indexing in one go. At some point you probably tried something like this:

```
In [38]: A[rows, columns] += 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-7d2300f59d51> in <module>()
----> 1 A[rows, columns] += 1

ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

Here numpy casts your lists of indices to arrays, then tries to [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) them out to the same shape, which fails because they have incompatible dimensions. To make it succeed, you can make `rows` into an `(n, 1)` array and `columns` into a `(1, m)` array, where `m` and `n` are the number of individual row/column indices. That way they can be expanded along the size 1 dimensions to size `(n, m)`, and used to index into `A`:

```
r = np.array(rows)
c = np.array(columns)
A[r[:, None], c[None, :]] += 1
print(A)
# [[ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Indexing with `None` is the same thing as using `np.newaxis` - it has the effect of inserting a new dimension of size 1.

There is actually a convenience function, [`np.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html), for generating multidimensional indices from a sequence of 1D indices:

```
A = np.zeros((8, 8))
A[np.ix_(rows, columns)] += 1
```

Comment: I agree that your result is surely more elegent than mine ... however, I would like to point out that one _can_ change elements of `A` using advanced indexing see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15692289/4367286)

Comment: @plonser That is true, but only when assigning to the result of a single indexing expression. Assigning to the result of chained indexing (e.g. `A[x][y] = ...`) will only work if the first set of indices is a slice or an integer (i.e. non-fancy indexing). I'll edit my answer to make the distinction a bit clearer.

Comment: This method uses huge amount of memory

Comment: @bluesky What are you comparing it to?

Answer (score 4):

`rows` needs to be a 'column' vector, e.g.

```
rows=[[0],[1],[5]]
cols=[2,3]
A[rows,cols]+=1
```

Sometimes a 2 stage indexing works, `A[rows][:,cols]`, but not always.  In particular it doesn't in this case where `rows` is not a slice.  `A[rows]` is now a copy, so changing it does not change `A`.

There are various ways of indexing this block.  `plonser's` use of `product` works, though I've rarely seen it used with `numpy`.

`np.ix_` is a handy tool for doing this:

```
In [70]: np.ix_([0,1,5],[2,3])
Out[70]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [5]]), array([[2, 3]]))
```

`np.newaxis` also turns a row vector into a column:

```
rows=np.array([0,1,5])
cols=np.array([2,3])
A[rows[:,None],cols]
```

This pairing of column and row vectors works because `numpy` broadcasts them to produce the `(3,2)` array of indices.

`itertools.product` produces the same set of indices, but as a list (or generator) of tuples

```
In [80]: list(itertools.product([0,1,5],[2,3]))
Out[80]: [(0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (5, 2), (5, 3)]
In [84]: tuple(np.array(list(itertools.product([0,1,5],[2,3]))).T)
Out[84]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1, 5, 5]), array([2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first getting all coordinates using `itertool.product`

```
import itertools
coord = np.array(list(itertools.product(rows,columns)))
```

and then using advanced indexing

```
A[tuple(coord.T)] += 1
```

As mentioned in other answers advanced indexing usually gives a copy. However, if treated correctly it still works as argued [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15692289/4367286).

Comment: I agree that one has to be careful with advanced indexing and copies ... however my code works fine which is why I don't understand I have been downvoted