# Error when indexing with 2 dimensions in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Why does this work:

```
>>> (tf[:,[91,1063]])[[0,3,4],:]
array([[ 0.04480133,  0.01079433],
       [ 0.11145042,  0.        ],
       [ 0.01177578,  0.01418614]])
```

But this does not:

```
>>> tf[[0,3,4],[91,1063]]
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
tf[:,[91,1063]])[[0,3,4],:]
```

operates in 2 steps, first selecting 2 columns, and then 3 rows from that result

```
tf[[0,3,4],[91,1063]]
```

tries to select `tf[0,91]`, `tf[3,1063]` and `ft[4, oops]`.

```
tf[[[0],[3],[4]], [91,1063]]
```

should work, giving the same result as your first expression.  think of the 1st list being a column, selecting rows.

```
tf[np.array([0,3,4])[:,newaxis], [91,1063]]
```

is another way of generating that column index array

```
tf[np.ix_([0,3,4],[91,1063])]
```

`np.ix_` can help generate these index arrays.

```
In [140]: np.ix_([0,3,4],[91,1063])
Out[140]: 
(array([[0],
        [3],
        [4]]), array([[  91, 1063]]))
```

These column and row arrays are broadcast together to produce a 2d array of coordinates

```
[[(0,91), (0,1063)]
 [(3,91), ...     ]
 ....             ]]
```

This is the relevant part of the docs: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing

I'm basically repeating my answer to [Composite Index updates for Numpy Matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519050/composite-index-updates-for-numpy-matrices/29519999#29519999)