# When does advanced indexing on structured masked arrays *really* return a copy?

Tags: numpy, indexing, structured-array, masked-array

When I have a structured masked array with boolean indexing, under what conditions do I get a view and when do I get a copy?  The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) says that advanced indexing always returns a copy, but this is not true, since something like `X[X>0]=42` is technically advanced indexing, but the assignment works.  My situation is more complex:

I want to set the mask of a particular field based on a criterion from another field, so I need to get the field, apply the boolean indexing, and get the mask.  There are 3! = 6 orders of doing so.

Preparation:

```
In [83]: M = ma.MaskedArray(random.random(400).view("f8,f8,f8,f8")).reshape(10, 10)

In [84]: crit = M[:, 4]["f2"] > 0.5
```

1. Field - index - mask (fails):

   ```
   In [85]: M["f3"][crit, 3].mask = True

   In [86]: print(M["f3"][crit, 3].mask)
   [False False False False False]
   ```
2. Index - field - mask (fails):

   ```
   In [87]: M[crit, 3]["f3"].mask = True

   In [88]: print(M[crit, 3]["f3"].mask)
   [False False False False False]
   ```
3. Index - mask - field (fails):

   ```
   In [94]: M[crit, 3].mask["f3"] = True

   In [95]: print(M[crit, 3].mask["f3"])
   [False False False False False]
   ```
4. Mask - index - field (fails):

   ```
   In [101]: M.mask[crit, 3]["f3"] = True

   In [102]: print(M.mask[crit, 3]["f3"])
   [False False False False False]
   ```
5. Field - mask - index (succeeds):

   ```
   In [103]: M["f3"].mask[crit, 3] = True

   In [104]: print(M["f3"].mask[crit, 3])
   [ True  True  True  True  True]

   # set back to False so I can try method #6

   In [105]: M["f3"].mask[crit, 3] = False

   In [106]: print(M["f3"].mask[crit, 3])
   [False False False False False]
   ```
6. Mask - field - index (succeeds):

   ```
   In [107]: M.mask["f3"][crit, 3] = True

   In [108]: print(M.mask["f3"][crit, 3])
   [ True  True  True  True  True]
   ```

So, it looks like indexing must come *last*.

Comment: The duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691740/does-assignment-with-advanced-indexing-copy-array-data addresses the `__setitem__` v `__getitem__` issue fine.  But I think there are nuances here that need further exploration - this is a structured array and masked.  So there's the question of how field indexing plays with element indexing, and how the `mask` can be set.  I propose reopening this.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of `__setitem__` v. `__getitem__` is important, but with structured array and masking it's a little harder to sort out when a `__getitem__` is first making a copy.

Regarding the structured arrays, it shouldn't matter whether the field index occurs first or the element.  However some releases appear to have a bug in this regard.  I'll try to find a recent SO question where this was a problem.

With a masked array, there's the question of how to correctly modify the mask.  The `.mask` is a property that accesses the underlying `._mask` array.  But that is fetched with `__getattr__`.  So the simple `setitem` v `getitem` distinction does not apply directly.

Lets skip the structured bit first

```
In [584]: M = np.ma.MaskedArray(np.arange(4))

In [585]: M
Out[585]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 999999)

In [586]: M.mask
Out[586]: False

In [587]: M.mask[[1,2]]=True
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-587-9010ee8f165e> in <module>()
----> 1 M.mask[[1,2]]=True

TypeError: 'numpy.bool_' object does not support item assignment
```

Initially `mask` is a scalar boolean, not an array.

This works

```
In [588]: M.mask=np.zeros((4,),bool)  # change mask to array

In [589]: M
Out[589]: 
masked_array(data = [0 1 2 3],
             mask = [False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [590]: M.mask[[1,2]]=True

In [591]: M
Out[591]: 
masked_array(data = [0 -- -- 3],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

This does not

```
In [592]: M[[1,2]].mask=True

In [593]: M
Out[593]: 
masked_array(data = [0 -- -- 3],
             mask = [False  True  True False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

`M[[1,2]]` is evidently the copy, and the assignment is to its `mask` attribute, not `M.mask`.

....

A masked array has `.__setmask__` method.  You can study that in `np.ma.core.py`.  And the mask property is defined with

```
mask = property(fget=_get_mask, fset=__setmask__, doc="Mask")
```

So `M.mask=...` does use this.

So it looks like the problem case is doing

```
M.__getitem__(index).__setmask__(values)
```

hence the copy.  The `M.mask[]=...` is doing

```
M._mask.__setitem__(index, values)
```

since `_getmask` just does `return self._mask`.

---

```
M["f3"].mask[crit, 3] = True
```

works because `M['f3']` is a view.  (`M[['f1','f3']]` is ok for get, but doesn't work for setting).

`M.mask["f3"]` is also a view.  I'm not entirely sure of the order the relevant get and sets.  `__setmask__` has code that deals specifically with compound dtype (structured).

=========================

Looking at a structured array, without the masking complication, the indexing order matters

```
In [607]: M1 = np.arange(16).view("i,i")

In [609]: M1[[3,4]]['f1']=[3,4]          # no change   
In [610]: M1[[3,4]]['f1']
Out[610]: array([7, 9], dtype=int32)

In [611]: M1['f1'][[3,4]]=[1,2]    # change
In [612]: M1
Out[612]: 
array([(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 1), (8, 2), (10, 11), (12, 13), (14, 15)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

So we still have a `__getitem__` followed by a `__setitem__`, and we have to pay attention as to whether the get returns a view or a copy.

Answer (score 0):

This is because although advanced indexing returns a copy, *assigning* to advanced indexing still works.  Only the method where advanced indexing is the *last* operation is assigning to advanced indexing (through `__setitem__`).